# How do I use pathlib & csv module to write?

Tags: python, file, csv

I use csv module to create a csv file. If I use build-in open function, the code is like this

```
import csv
...
csvFileObj = open(file.name, 'w')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFileObj)
```

But I don't know how to do that with pathlib, if I use the code like this

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path
...
csvFileObj = Path.cwd() / file.name
csvFileObj.open("w", encoding="utf-8")
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFileObj)
```

I got the error

```
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFileObj)
TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method
```

Comment: `csvFileObj.open("w", encoding="utf-8")` returns the open file object; `csvFileObj` itself is not a file object but a `Path()` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`csvFileObj` is a `Path` object. You should pass to `csv.writer` a file object instead:

```
with csvFileObj.open("w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(file)
```

Comment: So Path object has read/write method but csv read/writer method need a file object!